# Push notifications are sent to different app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am implementing Push Notifications for two of my Apps which are in iTunes. I have installed both Apps in my iPhone. When they register to my provider (server), I can see that Device ID and Device Token for both apps is the same.

I sent a push notification to app A from the provider, but it was delivered on my iPhone to app B. It obviously happens since both apps are registered with same device token.

Shouldn't APNS provide unique device token? Is there any additional parameter I can send to APNS to differentiate the Apps? I have generated different certificates for both of these apps and I'm using corresponding certificates to push notifications.

Answer (score 4):

The device token is the same for all Apps running on the same device. You differentiate the Apps by using different certificates for different Apps. The certificate lets the APN server know to which App the message should be delivered.

Comment: I would add that you should check if you did not upload the same certificate for both apps to your push provider.

Comment: Thanks Eran & Nick, How do I create app specific certificate?

Comment: The APN certificate is always app specific. You create it in the iOS provisioning portal in the App Ids Tab. Each Application should have its own App Id, and once you create that App Id, you can enable push notifications for that App Id and create the certificate. You can see the full process here : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1